# SAF - Java Unzip performance very bad at file loading

Tags: android, file, deprecated, unzip, storage-access-framework

I am trying to migrate my Android app to Storage Access Framework in case they deprecate file level access to the user's device storage (as it seems).

My app has to unpack a zip file and the following code is intended to perform that operation:

```
private boolean unpackZip(String targetPath, String zipFilePathUri //zipFilePath)
{       
     InputStream inputStream;
     ZipInputStream zInputStream;
     try 
     {
         inputStream =getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(zipFilePathUri));

         //here's the old code
         //inputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath); 
         //ZipFile zfile=new ZipFile(inputStream);

         int maxEntries;
         File mainfmd = new File(targetPath);
         zInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));
         ZipEntry zipEntry;
         int entriesCounter=0;
         while ((zipEntry = zInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
    ....
    ....
```

How it can be noticed there is a different implementation when SAF comes into place.
I experienced very bad performance when using getContentResolver().openInputStream, indeed I see that the real unpacking starts after a long pause in the app functioning, while it was very quick before.
Am I wrong at believing that?

Comment: how do you `"see that the real unpacking starts after a long pause"`? did you try to add some `Log.d` after `openInputStream()`, after `new ZipInputStream` and inside the while loop? if so, when are they shown? after what delays?

Comment: @pskink the while loop updates a progress bar, and I compare with the previous version of the app, I notice a very long pause in the SAF version before the progress starts.

Comment: is that `while` loop  called in some background thread? if so, how do you pass the current progress?

Comment: @pskink it is a service, the progress value is broadcasted

Comment: is that `while` loop called in some background thread? are you using `IntentService` for example? the docs say: *"IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through Context.startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a **worker thread**, and stops itself when it runs out of work."*

Comment: @pskink yes it is so, it worked very smoothly, now something changed with SAF

Comment: ok so first try to add those `Log.d` and watch the logcat and check if input stream processing is really the bottleneck here

Comment: @pskink It seems that the entire loop is performed, then the progress bar starts to be updated, but it is progressing gradually as it should do. What is the problem?

Comment: your broadcasts, use `Handler`s instead, more: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui

Comment: @pskink why does it happen only with the new SAF version?

Comment: i have no idea why